# Boost.python pull object into local scope for read access

Tags: python, c++, boost, scope, boost-python

I am exporting a C++ function to Python using Boost.Python. In this function, I would like to access a Python object on the local stack frame, *without* the need for this object to be accessed on the Python side.

Example: I have a C++ object `X` and a C++ function `cppfun` exported to Python, and then following code,

```
x = X()

def fun():
    cppfun()
    # no explicit access to x
```

Inside `cppfun` I can access the local stack frame using `PyEval_GetLocals`, but since the
Python side does not contain any reference to `x`, this object will not be in that local stack frame (similarly, if you `print(locals())` inside `fun`, `x` will not be there unless you add a reference to it, e.g. `print(x)`).

Is there any way in which I can access `x` inside `cppfun`, that is, can I somehow force Python to pull it into the `locals` without accessing it within `fun` on the Python side? I tried simply running `boost::python::eval("x")` but that runs in the wrong scope as well.

**added:** so I do *not* want to make the `x` from the outer frame writeable inside `fun` or something like that (I know that's not possible); this question is purely about how to get read access to a variable from the outer frame without accessing it on the Python side.

Answer (score 0):

One can access the outer scope through the use of [`PyEval_GetGlobals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/c-api/reflection.html#PyEval_GetGlobals), which returns dictionary of the global variables in the current execution *frame*.  It is fairly similar to the Python builtin [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) function, which returns the global symbol table of the module in which the function is defined.  However, frame stacks are handled slightly differently between standard modules and extension modules.  For extension modules, the current execution *frame* is the caller, and thus `PyEval_GetGlobals()` will return the global symbols for the caller's module, rather than the extension module's globals.

Alternative, one can obtain a handle to the current frame via [`PyEval_GetFrame()`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/c-api/reflection.html#PyEval_GetFrame), then walk through the stack, examining each *frame*'s local (`f_local`) and global (`f_global`) dictionary.

---

Here is a complete minimal example demonstrating both techniques and the subtle differences between them.  In the example, `get_global()` will use `PyEval_GetGlobals()`,and `search_stack_locals()` will examine the local dictionary for each frame in the stack.

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

namespace detail {

/// @brief Return a handle to a global variable.  If one is not found, then
///        None is returned.
boost::python::object get_global(std::string name)
{
  // Borrow a reference from the locals dictionary to create a handle.
  // If PyEval_GetGlobals() returns NULL, then Boost.Python will throw.
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::dict globals(python::borrowed(PyEval_GetGlobals()));
  return globals.get(name);
}

/// @brief Search through the call stack for a variable.  If found, the
///        object is returned.  Otherwise, None.
boost::python::object search_stack_locals(std::string name)
{
  // Get a handle to the current frame.
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::object frame(python::borrowed(
    reinterpret_cast<PyObject*>(PyEval_GetFrame())));

  // Iterate through the stack's frames until the variable has been found
  // or the stack has been exhausted.
  while (frame)
  {
    // If the current frame has the desired variable, then return it.
    python::dict locals(frame.attr("f_locals"));
    if (locals.has_key(name))
    {
      return locals.get(name);
    }

    // Move up the stack.
    frame = frame.attr("f_back");
  }

  // Return None
  return python::object();
}

} // namespace detail

/// @brief Mockup function to demonstrate finding non-local variables.
boost::python::object cppfun(std::string name)
{
  return boost::python::make_tuple(
    detail::get_global(name), detail::search_stack_locals(name));
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::def("cppfun", &cppfun);
}
```

In `spam.py`:

```python
import example

x = 'spam.global.x'
y = 'spam.global.y'

def inner():
    for name in ('x', 'y', 'z'):
        print name, example.cppfun(name)

def outer():
    x = 'spam.outer.x'
    inner()
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> x = 'main.global.x'
>>> y = 'main.global.y'
>>> z = 'main.global.z'
>>> import spam
>>> spam.outer()
x ('spam.global.x', 'spam.outer.x')
y ('spam.global.y', 'main.global.y')
z (None, 'main.global.z')
```

Take note that when using `PyEval_GetGlobals()`, the `example` extension module used the caller's module's global symbol table (`spam`).  The globals declared in the interpreter's main namespace were only found when iterating through the stack.